# Not able to set my windows jenkins server as HTTPS

Tags: jenkins, https, pfx, windows-server-2019, jks

I'm trying to turn my jenkins server to `HTTPS`.

I got the `pfx` file, and I created from it the `jks` file.

Afterward I've updated my `jenkins.config` file with the below line:

`<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8080 --httpsKeyStore="C:\Users\aman\.jenkins\clientcert.jks" --httpsKeyStorePassword="######" --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>`

but getting this exception when trying to start jenkins:

`java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory Caused by: winstone.WinstoneException: Error getting the SSL context object Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key 2022-08-17 18:44:56.770+0000 [id=1]    SEVERE              winstone.Logger#logInternal: Container startup failed`

I tried to google but couldn't find any solution.
some more details:

OS - Windows server 2019

Jenkins version:  2.346.3 LTS

Installation: thought war file

java version: java 8u333

The httpsKeyStorePassword is the same password I wrote in the destination keystore password while running this command:

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore my_cert.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore clientcert.jks -deststoretype JKS`